# How to make WordPress keep me signed in?

Tags: login

When I log in to my WordPress blog, there's a checkbox that says *Remember me*.  But whether or not I check this, if I come back in a day or two I have to log in again, so it doesn't appear that this checkbox does anything.  (My Google account, by contrast, hasn't ever once asked me to re-login on this computer, for more than a year now.)

How do I make WP *actually remember me?*

Comment: Check your browser's cookie/security settings.

Answer (score 0):

The cookies are set to expire two weeks from the time they are created. From the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies)

The expiration period is set in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` as shown below:

```
$expiration = time() + apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember );
```

You can use the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter to change this value.

Comment: @PieterGoosen - I get it now. I've started using anchor text in links.

Answer (score -4):

Does it require you to type your user name when you come back in a few days? If you have to type that, then yes - something is wrong with your cookies perhaps.

If it fills in your user name only, its working as intended. Remember me shouldn't maintain the logged in session indefinitely, only remember the user's name last used. Password will still be required.

Comment: Well then who in the world *intended* such a broken behavior?  Because that's exactly what a well-behaved website is supposed to do when you tell it to keep you logged in: **keep you logged in.**  (Case in point: Google.)

Comment: WordPress remember me does eliminate the need to enter username AND password until the cookies expire.